# I'm getting error when i tried List<Entity> to Dto with MapStruct

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

```
public class Account {

    private String accountId
    private List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();
```

---

```
public abstract class Transaction {
    private double amount;
```

---

```
public class AccountEntity extends BaseEntity{
    @OneToMany
    private List<TransactionEntity> transactions;
```

---

```
public class TransactionEntity extends BaseEntity{
    @Id
    private String transactionId;
    private double amount;
    private String type;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "accountId", referencedColumnName = "accountNumber")
    private AccountEntity account;
```

---

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface AccountMapper {
    
    Account AccountEntityToAccount(AccountEntity accountEntity);

    AccountEntity AccountToAccountEntity(Account account);
```

My AccountEntityToAccount method is getting error which is
The return type Transaction is an abstract class or interface. Provide a non abstract / non interface result type or a factory method.
Account AccountEntityToAccount(AccountEntity accountEntity);

how could i solve this problem. My Transaction class should be abstract i can not change abstract keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a method to create the correct Transaction from the TransactionEntity supplied.

Reading the code you probably want to have something like the following:

```java
Transaction fromTransactionEntity(TransactionEntity entity){
  if (entity == null){
    return null;
  }
  if ( entity.getType().equals("something") ) {
    return toSomethingTransaction(entity);
  }
  if ( entity.getType().equals("other") ) {
    return toOtherTransaction(entity);
  }
  throw new IllegalStateException("unsupported transaction found, cannot instantiate object.");
}

SomethingTransaction toSomethingTransaction(TransactionEntity entity);

OtherTransaction toOtherTransaction(TransactionEntity entity);
```

In the other direction you probably want to do the same thing. (when `1.5.0` is released you can use `@SubclassMapping` for this instead of manually writing the instanceof. currently at `1.5.0.RC1` stage.)

```java
TransactionEntity toTransactionEntity(Transaction transaction){
  if (transaction == null){
    return null;
  }
  if (transaction instanceof SomethingTransaction){
    return fromSomethingTransaction(transaction);
  }
  if (transaction instanceof OtherTransaction){
    return toOtherTransaction(entity);
  }
  throw new IllegalStateException("unsupported transaction found, cannot store it.");
}

@Mapping( target = "type", constant = "something" )
TransactionEntity fromSomethingTransaction(SomethingTransaction transaction);

@Mapping( target = "type", constant = "other" )
TransactionEntity fromOtherTransaction(OtherTransaction transaction);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is

```
private List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();
```

if you have another class which extends Transaction then use this for your generic in the list. Otherwise how should Mapstuct now which class to create for that List

Comment: Hi, but i have 2 Transaction subclass which extends Transaction class. I dont want to give specific subClass type to Account.class

Comment: But if you don´t want to give a specific Subclass the how should mapstruct know which of your two subclasses should be chosen in the Mapping? It is absolutely possible to do such a mapping in mapstruct, but you have to do it explicitly (@AfterMapping, @BeforeMapping or default mapping could be used). For the beginning you could change "List<Transaction>" to "List<? extends Transaction>" and see if this gives you a different error from which to continue.